# {Maya 2017} Problem with Knee Joint Target

Tags: maya, rigging, joints, bones

I am not very experienced with Game Development or Character Design/Rigging, but I am trying to learn and have hit my first roadblock with rigging a character.

I used Maya 2017's QuickRig function and it worked out alright except for the Knees bend backwards. I tried shifting or rotating the Knee target node but it does not move unlike the elbow nodes did.

I believe all I need to do it get the Knee Target node on the front of my character.

Any Tips? Linked below are screenshots to help visualize my problem.

Character Rig: https://gyazo.com/bee70568fbacc473e095631185443a48

Knee Bend Problem: https://gyazo.com/d4b1ba9a542dbc18ffb2ba14db71c931